# Looking for information about a space-related footage and film resource

Tags: apollo-program, history, project-gemini

There once was a website called *Space Films*, I think that was it. The web site featured restored official video footage from NASA and others of various space launches over the years (i.e. Gemini, Mercury, Apollo, etc.).

I think the proprietor of the website even sold "space stuff"..

I can't find the site or remember what the name was. Yes, I've done a web search w/ no luck.

Any one of the space fans here remember what this website was called and if it still exists?

Comment: I adjusted your title to make sure nobody sends you to Movies SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking exclusively for a link that can rot (and probably has in the past), without any kind of useful explanation possible in answers.

Comment: I understand what you are asking for. But, the proprietor of the website was a retired professional space videographer. He had restored a LOT of the films from NASA. The web searches are truly worthless in searching for things like this. I'm hoping that I can tap into some of the collective knowledge of this group to determine the website.

Comment: I'm not sure about the rules here, but the Demonoid torrent site has a 6.64GB torrent:  "NASA Space Exploration Rockets Missiles Historic Films ebooks" uploaded on Aug03 2016. There are ~75 films dating from late 50's to Skylab. (mostly at 480p resolution)

Comment: If your question will be closed, don't worry on that - you are essentially asking for a link, and thus you have a quite good chance to get it in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Found it! Someone provided me with a contact.

The website is [Spacecraft Films](http://www.spacecraftfilms.com).. They provide an extensive, historically accurate collection of space related films & DVDs. They do a lot of research on their films. Hence, the reason that I think it meets the standards of space stackexchange.

Trying to find a small space-related site in a web search is terribly painful.